# Generating unique spell number based on different combinations of variables and their values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

A sample dataset is provided below:

```
fact_code line_code date         style   run_rank style_spell
1206      1206029   2017-04-05   283674d        1           1
1206      1206029   2017-04-06   283674d        2           0
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...
1206      1206029   2017-04-18   283674d        7           0
1206      1206046   2017-05-01   283674d        1           1
1206      1206046   2017-05-15   283674d        2           1    
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...
1206      1206046   2017-05-21   283674d        7           0
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...
1222      1222003   2017-09-11   65654          1           1
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...
1222      1222003   2017-09-19   65654          8           0
```

The `dput()` output without `...` is:

```
structure(list(fact_code = c(1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 
1206L, 1222L, 1222L), line_code = c(1206029L, 1206029L, 1206029L, 
1206046L, 1206046L, 1206046L, 1222003L, 1222003L), date = c("05/04/2017", 
"06/04/2017", "18/04/2017", "01/05/2017", "15/05/2017", "21/05/2017", 
"11/09/2017", "19/09/2017"), style = c("283674d", "283674d", 
"283674d", "283674d", "283674d", "283674d", "65654", "65654"), 
    run_rank = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L), style_spell = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The variables `fact_code` stands for the garments factory code, `line_code` means factory line code, `style` is a character variable for the garment style that the line is producing on a given date, and `run_rank` stands for ranking of the production days. `style_spell` is an indicator variable that takes the value 1 to indicate commencement of new production spell by a factory line for a particular garment style and 0 otherwise.

I would like to create a new variable, `spell_num`, which indicates the current spell number for the style that the factory line is producing. So the variable would like this:

```
fact_code line_code date         style   run_rank style_spell spell_num
1206      1206029   2017-04-05   283674d        1           1         1
1206      1206029   2017-04-06   283674d        2           0         1
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...       ...
1206      1206029   2017-04-18   283674d        7           0         1
1206      1206046   2017-05-01   283674d        1           1         1
1206      1206046   2017-05-15   283674d        2           1         2    
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...       ...
1206      1206046   2017-05-21   283674d        7           0         2         
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...       ...  
1222      1222003   2017-09-11   65654          1           1         1
...       ...       ...          ...          ...         ...       ...
1222      1222003   2017-09-19   65654          8           0         1
```

```
structure(list(fact_code = c(1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 
1206L, 1222L, 1222L), line_code = c(1206029L, 1206029L, 1206029L, 
1206046L, 1206046L, 1206046L, 1222003L, 1222003L), date = c("05/04/2017", 
"06/04/2017", "18/04/2017", "01/05/2017", "15/05/2017", "21/05/2017", 
"11/09/2017", "19/09/2017"), style = c("283674d", "283674d", 
"283674d", "283674d", "283674d", "283674d", "65654", "65654"), 
    run_rank = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L), style_spell = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), spell_num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The variable, `spell_num`, for a given factory line (`line_code`) producing a given style (`style`) takes the value 1 when on the first production day and, therefore, commencement of a new spell (i.e. `run_rank` = 1), the value of the indicator variable, `style_spell` is 1. For example, in the first row, line 1206029 first starts producing the style 283674d on 2017-04-05 and therefore, `style_spell` and `spell_num` are both equal to 1.

From the next subsequent date/production day (i.e. `run_rank` >= 2), the value of the variable `style_spell` changes to 0.

However, `spell_num` assumes the value 1 for a given line and style until `style_spell` changes to 1 again. This can be happen in two ways. Firstly, if we have a new factory line producing the same style (for example when line 1206046 starts producing style 283674d on 2017-04-18 after line 1206029 ends its production on the 7th day).

Or when a same line re-produces the style after a discontinuity of two weeks. For example, line 1206046 has two spells; the first spell takes place where `style_spell` = 1 which is on the first production day for the style 283674d i.e. 2017-05-01, therefore, corresponding to `run_rank` = 1. At the commencement of the second spell for line 1206046 on 2017-05-15, the value for `spell_num` changes to 2 from 1 to indicate that two weeks has lapsed and that the line now is in its second spell producing that particular style.

The variable `spell_num` will now assume that value of 2 unless there is a discontinuity or break of two weeks in the production of this style, or when a new line starts producing the same or a different new style.

I have been trying to generate this intended variable by using the code below:

```
  dplyr::filter(style_spell == 1) %>%
  dplyr::select(fact_code, line_code, date, style, run_rank, Diff, Diff_max, style_multi, style_spell)
```

```
  dplyr::group_by(line_code, date, style, run_rank) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(style_spell_num = row_number())
```

The code can be broken down in two stages where in the first stage, I attempt to create a subset of the data where `style_spell` = 1. After operating on the subset, my plan was to merge the variable created on this subset to the main data, df.

However, I am not getting the intended result. And, moreover, I would ideally like a code that can create the variable, `spell_num` in one step i.e. using the main data, `df` rather than operating on its subset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "However, I am not getting the intended result." Can you be more specific about how the result differs from your intentions?

Comment: Also, could provide sample data in an nicer format? All the `...` make it annoying to import. Perhaps share some copy/pasteable data with `dput()` to supplement the table, where the `...` convey meaning to humans but not to R.

Comment: The values for ```spell_num``` that I am getting instead is 1s for all the rows. Rather, it should assume the values as spelled out in the second data frame. Also, I have copied and pasted the ```dput()``` from R. Notice that I have excluded ```...```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the `dput`---makes it much easier.

Near as I can tell, this is what you want:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fact_code, line_code, style) %>%
  mutate(my_answer = cumsum(style_spell))
# # A tibble: 8 x 8
# # Groups:   fact_code, line_code, style [3]
#   fact_code line_code date       style   run_rank style_spell spell_num my_answer
#       <int>     <int> <chr>      <chr>      <int>       <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1      1206   1206029 05/04/2017 283674d        1           1         1         1
# 2      1206   1206029 06/04/2017 283674d        2           0         1         1
# 3      1206   1206029 18/04/2017 283674d        7           0         1         1
# 4      1206   1206046 01/05/2017 283674d        1           1         1         1
# 5      1206   1206046 15/05/2017 283674d        2           1         2         2
# 6      1206   1206046 21/05/2017 283674d        7           0         2         2
# 7      1222   1222003 11/09/2017 65654          1           1         1         1
# 8      1222   1222003 19/09/2017 65654          8           0         1         1
```

I'm not 100% sure that `style` should be in the `group_by`. I can't really tell from your description, and for the small sample of data it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I have tried your code and works elegantly! And this was exactly what I was looking for.